# Opening and editing java classes in not java bytecode view

Tags: java

How to open and edit java class files? I've searched, but I either found how to open them without being able to edit them, or how to be able to edit only the bytecode. I want to be able to read and edit `.class` in the "normal" view. (as source code, not bytecode)

Comment: What do you think a `.class` file contains?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is basically impossible.  The ".class" files do not contain source code, and do not contain enough information to reconstruct the original source code.

*If you are a bit lucky*, a good decompiler would be able to create compilable source code that means the same thing as the ".class" files.  However:

- That decompiled source code won't have the original comments.
- The original names of any local variables are not recoverable.
- The structure of the decompiled code may be different; e.g. string concatenation, `for` loops and `try/catch` structures may be transformed.
- The code is not guaranteed to be correct, or compilable at all.  (It depends on the decompiler, and how well it deals with the version of Java you are trying to decompile.)

And if the code you are trying to edit was obfuscated, then your chances of success are *greatly* reduced.  An obfuscator deliberately transforms the ".class" files to remove useful information, and to confuse decompilers.

---

To my knowledge, no IDE supports editing of ".class" files like this.

Answer (score 0):

Before my suggestion, I wanna point out that as far as I've searched, there has yet to exist a *free* decompiler that allows you to edit the source code produced, and save it automatically. I believe this is due to decompilers only being able to attempt to decompile the code, and the source code produced is not always exact/error free/compilable.

**What you can do**

You must use a decompiler, such as [JAD](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)), copy the source code that it produces and paste it into a new file.

As for the download link, you can find that on [google](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&ei=z4LlU-XxINfpoATdzoKIAw&q=JAD+decompiler&oq=JAD+decompiler&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.3..0l5.2499.8458.0.8631.23.17.4.8.8.1.269.2085.0j12j2.14.0....0...1c.1.51.mobile-gws-hp..3.20.1459.3.VrFbgTCLudc), as I am unsure of the safest place to get it.

A decompiler ***does its best*** at converting the content (bytecode) within `.class` files into readable Java source code. Not only will some identifiers (method, variable and class names) will be replaced with generic names, meaning `String name;` in bytecode might decompile to `String aString1;`. Random variables might also be generated (`tmp` variables), which can lead to the produced code being unable to compile.